# Do we need additional license to dump goldengate trail logs to kafka?

Tags: oracle, logs, change-data-capture, goldengate

We have a Oracle (12c) GoldenGate license only (we do not have an oracle goldengate for big data).

We need to transfer the gg trail logs to kafka then to hdfs.

Do we need to buy the oracle goldengate for big data license to use the kafka connect?

**Research we did:**

These are the following kafka connect we found:

1. kafka connect for big data: Probably needs additional license
   https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/goldengate/big-data/19.1/gadbd/using-kafka-handler.html#GUID-2561CA12-9BAC-454B-A2E3-2D36C5C60EE5
2. Kafka Connect handler: Where do we get it? Which licenses do we need?
   https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/goldengate/big-data/19.1/gadbd/using-kafka-connect-handler.html

Other links:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107652/how-can-i-configure-the-kafka-connect-handler-in-ogg-for-hdfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you have to buy another license (for BigData) or somehow transform your current one.

Basically there are these ways to implement CDC from Oracle DB.

- Oracle streams - deprecated but still technically usable(no license cost)
- Parse binary format of Oracle redo-logs. GoldenGate and Shareplex can do that. Both product require SW license. Otherwise it is best choice from performance a stability perspective.
- Logminer, this is Oracle's internal tool to view content of archived/online redologs. Couple of free/cheap tools are based on Logminner. Cons:

  - Since ver 18c deprecated option "continuous mine"
  - High CPU usage (on single CPU core)
  - Won't scale good (can have backlogs under high load)
- Database Change Notifications(Continuous Query Notification), I do not know much about it. I'm not sure how it handles restarts/failovers/outages.

[Continuous Query Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47095776/836215)

[SharePlex](https://support.quest.com/technical-documents/shareplex/9.2/installation-and-setup-for-oracle-source/11)

Comment: We already tried log miner and xstream and they are slow on heavy load and we currently already have the gg trail logs being dumped. Do we also need a license for Kafka Connect handler:
https://github.com/imanzano/GoldenGateConfluentKafkaConnector? Is there a way to read the gg trail logs without additional license?

Comment: My personal experience is that you would need the Big Data license, but you should not be getting licensing advice on this forum (or any other) in general. For accurate answers to Oracle licensing questions, you need to talk to Oracle Sales.